# Level Timer- How to Create Time Limit in Unity?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, timer

How do I create a GUI script in Unity that will restart level at a certain amount of seconds, so the level is timed? For example at 30 seconds the level restarts or goes back to main menu.

Here is my Timer Script

[image]

The level that I am on is marked as 0 in the build settings. 
The Main Menu is a different number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using `OnGUI` and `JavaScript`/`UnityScript`. Use the [new](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) Unity `UI` and `C#`. Simply create a text and attach the text to the `timerText` slot, you will be able to see the timer counting from 0 to 30 or to any passed in value.

**C#**:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(reloadTimer(30));
}

public Text timerText;

IEnumerator reloadTimer(float reloadTimeInSeconds)
{
    float counter = 0;

    while (counter < reloadTimeInSeconds)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        timerText.text = counter.ToString();
        yield return null;
    }

    //Load new Scene
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}
```

Make sure to include using `UnityEngine.SceneManagement;` and `using UnityEngine.UI;`

**JavaScript**:

```
public var timerText : UI.Text;

function Start () {
    reloadTimer(30);
}

function reloadTimer(reloadTimeInSeconds : float){
    var counter = 0;

    while (counter < reloadTimeInSeconds)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        timerText.text = counter.ToString();
        yield;
    }

    //Load new Scene
    UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way this could be in unity script instead of c#. I could use it but I wont completely understand for a while. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Assets/timerc#.cs(11,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Text' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: @colt1911 Read the last line of my answer.

Comment: Updated my script with JavaScript. It compiled, but I did not test it to see if it works. I suggest you learn JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you. I know JavaScript better. This will help a lot.